# How to understand what is the process?

Tags: perl, email, freebsd

I have server with FreeBSD. And I receive message from my hoster that this server send spam. In process list I see that:

```
# ps -U www
PID  TT  STAT      TIME COMMAND
14695  ??  Ss   936:32,05 mail (perl5.8.9)
14696  ??  Rs   946:48,67 mail (perl5.8.9)
29638  ??  Ss   834:23,55 mail (perl5.8.9)
```

How to know what is the process? I think that is some Perl script. How to find this script?

Answer (score 1):

If you think someone has compromised the security on your host then the best thing to do is to reinstall and restore backups

If this is not possible then

```
ps xwwwU www
```

Will give more information about the processes

Comment: Sorry, but this also doesn't help:


# ps xwwwU www
  PID  TT  STAT      TIME COMMAND
  614  ??  S     32:00,92 nginx: worker process (nginx)
  616  ??  S     32:40,19 nginx: worker process (nginx)
14695  ??  Rs   946:23,75 mail (perl5.8.9)
14696  ??  Rs   956:50,19 mail (perl5.8.9)
19748  ??  R      0:06,76 /usr/local/sbin/httpd

Answer (score 0):

if you are receiving this in a input file.
I am not sure you need PID or TT(??).

Here's what you can do:

```
    use strict;

    my $file = "input.txt";
    open(FH, "<$file") or die "Could not open $file";

    foreach my $line (<FH>)
    {
        if($line =~ /^(\d+)\s+(.+?)\s+/) {
            my $pid = $1;
            my $tt  = $2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. He's not looking to parse anything. He wants to know what the processes are he is seeing.

Comment: Yes, you are right @simbabque. Thank you.
should I delete this answer?